# Face (in) a direction

Tags: phrases

Which one and why?

- To face a direction
- To face *in* a direction

Context: Use this method to ensure your character always faces in the direction they are moving in.

Comment: Face *in the* direction of...,

Comment: You can face North, or face in a Northerly direction. You can face forward, or in the direction of motion. Here I would prefer "in the direction", provided "they" refers to your character.

Comment: [***Both** forms occur*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=face+the+direction+of%2Cface+in+the+direction+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cface%20the%20direction%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cface%20in%20the%20direction%20of%3B%2Cc0) (with / without preposition ***in***). It's just a POB stylistic choice.

Comment: What means *they*?